# How to access database?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to access the database. I've downloaded the file where database credential reserved.

The file is mysql.php

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','user','password') or die("Connection error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('newadv',$conn) or die("Connection error: " . mysql_error());
```

IN the server how can I access the localhost and database.

The mysql.php file now is in server and the website is running.

I need to access the database from Mysql interface. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to google for an example?

Comment: You can google this with no issues, it is complete basic stuff.

Comment: I've tried in google. In google most of the answer are localhost in PC and not in server. I apologize for my ignorance. localhost in server? How can I access this?

Comment: OK. First of all, many developers start their coding in his PC. If the guy installs something like XAMPP, it will convert his PC into a web server. Then localhost means the server he is hosting. And, if you are using web hosting and the SQL server is on the same place, you can still use localhost, but if the SQL service is hosted on somewhere else, you have to enter the server host (IP or a Domain Name that points to the SQL server).

Comment: Localhost is relative - if you run your PHP script on the server, in localhost will be that server. IT is good practice to have php scripts and DB on one machine.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how can I access the sql server? I need to use the user interface of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got reply from webhosting service. They gave me the credentials to log in.

Thank you every one.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to connect with server.If database present on same server then use host as localhost & database server username & password.If they are on different server then in place of localhost provide the server host details.

like:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('111.255.255.254','root','root') or die("Connection error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('newadv',$conn) or die("Connection error: " . mysql_error());
```